# How to put jobs in a category for the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin for Jenkins

Tags: plugins, concurrency, build, jenkins

I have downloaded the TCB plugin for Jenkins.  I have several builds that run tests.  These builds must be run individually, as they access similar files that can cause tests to fail if more than one test build is running.  I have been trying to find the place where I put the builds into a "category", so I can throttle the whole test category down to 1/1.  I thought that it might be the Jenkins Views, but that did not do the job.  How do you add jobs to a category?

This tag discusses the solution I desire: [Jenkins: group jobs and limit build processors for this group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834677/jenkins-group-jobs-and-limit-build-processors-for-this-group).  The only problem is that it doesn't say how to add them to categories.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You set up categories in the global Jenkins configuration (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) and then assign jobs to categories.  See the "Per Project-Category" section in the [plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks!  I had set those up, but the groups I had set up had not appeared in the individual jobs - until it randomly decided to. Must have been some weird configuration thing, or not saving, or something - but it all works now.

Comment: @gareth_bowles can you tell how to create categories for jobs..i am unable to find any such option in the jenkins configuration

Comment: @thunderbird do you have the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin installed ?  The plugin docs linked above show you how to set up categories; feel free to add some details here if you're still having problems after reading the docs.

Comment: @gareth_bowles yea i just couldn't find where to setup the categories and its not mentioned very clearly in the plugin docs as well though i was finally able to figure out that the categories option is present at 'Mange Jenkins -> Configure System'.

Comment: It is clear how to create categories, but how do you assign jobs to categories?

Comment: Ok, on the job page you have to enable 'Throttle Concurrent Builds' and then you can select the category. That's why a search for 'category' did not find it on the page.