# creating job categories on jenkins for use with throttle concurrent build plugin

Tags: jenkins, hudson

How do i create job categories on Jenkins for use with the throttle concurrent build plugin.

The answer for the question in the link below didnt help.

[How to put jobs in a category for the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079051/how-to-put-jobs-in-a-category-for-the-throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin-for-jenk)

I cant see any option to configure categories in the global jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories can be configured at 'Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Throttle Concurrent Builds'.